# How to add DatePicker when I click on text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my MVC4 razor engine, I need to pick date from text box. It is my View:

```
<tr>
  <td>Start Date</td>
  <td>@Html.TextBox("RateListStartDate")</td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>End Date</td>
  <td>@Html.TextBox("RateListEndDate")</td>
</tr>
```

When I click on text box of start date or end date, it should display calendar.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly. Do you want to create an MVC helper for this or just use the jQuery DateTimePicker()?

Comment: Yes i need datepicker...dont know how to use in my .vbhtml(view page)..

Comment: Check this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZXj9ojFFk8), just change the `<input/>` to `@Html.Textbox`

Answer (score 5):

Since you use MVC, jQuery "should" already referenced in your layout page. You will also need the [jqueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/).

If the datepicker code is throwing erros at you, add the following 2 lines, to your view or your layouts page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Then you need to declare the elements, which should be get the datepicker functionality.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".getdate").each(function() {
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
});
```

and edit your Html.TextBoxFor() accordingly:

```
@Html.TextBox("RateListStartDate", new {@class="getdate"})
```

This should do the trick.
Kind regards

Comment: @Serv... no i dint reference the jquery files... how to reference jquery files???

Comment: I have updated my answer. jQuery should be there out of the box, but I am not sure for the jQueryUI files. Add those lines to your view/layout just in case

Comment: @Serv.. i did as u told... but it shows error like type or with expected in this line @Html.TextBoxFor("RateListStartDate", new {@class="getdate"})

Comment: Ah, my bad. I am constantly using TextBoxFor, but what you need is `@Html.TextBox(...)` without the for. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use jquery datepicker.
[DATEPICKER DEMO](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".datepicker").each(function() {
        $(this).datepicker();
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H9GKt/)

Answer (score 4):

```
<!doctype html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Restrict date range</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: -100, maxDate: "+0D" });
      $("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate",new Date());
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This isn't Razor syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#txtBoxId').datepicker();
    });
```

refer this to your Layout

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(function()
    {
        $("#date").datepicker();
        $("#date").datepicker
        ({
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yyyy"
        });
    });
</script>

<tr>
  <td>Start Date</td>
    <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label   col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "date" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
        </div>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td>End Date</td>
    <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label   col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "date" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
        </div>
</tr>
```